# Build an Android application via Nodejs

Tags: python, android, node.js, twilio

I want to build twilio SMS sender for Android. I have recently searched for it and found how to create via Android Studio, but it seems to be complicated for me. Then tried to search if I could use python for building Android application, but may be I was searching on wrong places, I can not find right answers. Than discovered that it's possible to build via Nodejs. I want it for me , not to upload anywhere only for my device.

I found AndroidJS.

```
mkdir twilio1
cd twilio1
mkdir assets
mkidr views
```

also I have created index.html in views directory and main.js in main app directory and then -->

```
npm install androidjs
npm install twilio
```

This is what I got

```
twilio1
|__views
|     |__index.html
|
|__assets
|
|__node_modules
|
|__main.js
|__package.json
```

I have pasted simple form from Bootstrap into index.html

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>SendME</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/androidjs.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/androidjs/lib/androidjs.js"></script> -->

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../assets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="../assets/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="text-center">

    <div id="app" class="app">

        <form class="form-signin">
            <img class="mb-4" src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72">

            <label for="inputTel" class="sr-only">Send To</label>
            <input type="tel" id="inputNumber" v-model="inputNumber" name="inputNumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Send To" maxlength="13" size="13" required autofocus>
            <label for="inputName" class="sr-only">Sending From</label>
            <input type="text" id="inputName" v-model="inputName" name="inputName" class="form-control" placeholder="Sending From" maxlength="11" size="11" required autofocus>
            <label for="inputText" class="sr-only">SMS Body</label>
            <input type="text" id="inputText" v-model="inputText" name="inputText" class="form-control" placeholder="SMS Body" maxlength="120" size="120" required autofocus>
            <div class="checkbox mb-3">
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" onclick="sendMsg()" type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

I have wrote this code in main.js

```
        const accountSid = 'XX';
        const authToken = 'XX';
        const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

        text = this.inputText
        mobile = this.inputNumber
        names = this.inputName


        function sendMsg() {
            client.messages
                .create({
                    body: text,
                    from: names,
                    to: mobile,
                })
        }
```

after that I pasted this into package.json

```
{
  "name": "twilio1",
  "app-name": "twilio1",
  "package-name" : "twilio1",
  "icon": "./assets/icon/icon.png",
  "permission": ["android.permission.INTERNET"],
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dist-path": "./dist",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "androidjs": "^1.0.5"
  }
}
```

Then I have copied androidjs.js from GitHub repository and pasted in assets and then put its src location in index.html. I thought it was ready and then I typed

```
androidjs b -f
```

and it is not working. There is just an error message -->

```
Invalid project type: undefined
```

Finally I want to know if it is even possible to build an application like this. Or if someone have created it already and can share it to me, please, share. And if it is possible help me to do it on right way. I have already created an app in python for windows , so I wanted to created it for android too, so. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

@Roman Smith you can give `webview` as type in your `package.json`.
go and checkout the docs https://android-js.github.io/docs